# how to resolve Error Cannot find symbol variable youtube_url in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am Stuck in `Error: Cannot find symbol variable youtube_url` in android studio everything is fine but this error stopping me to build gradle please help.

[image]

Comment: define a string value with name youtube_url in your strings and place url to load

Comment: Are you sure the R.string.youtube_url is not empty?

Comment: you obviously don't have that string resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove

activity.getString(R.string.youtube_url)

and write url of youtube video to be shown "www.youtube.com/key"

or 
define a string value with name youtube_url in your strings and place url to load

Answer (score 0):

Under your app folder, look for a folder called `res` then a folder called `values` then a file called `Strings.xml`  (`app/res/values/Strings.xml`).

The file likely looks like this:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My App</string>
</resources>
```

Inside there you need create another String!

```
<string name="youtube_url">Hello World</string>
```

You can read more here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources